# ocr algorithm used to extract text from image by mobile

Tags: ocr

what is the best ocr algorithm used to extract text from image by mobile
camera?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your application requirements.

Usually OCR engine can only return characters, font, word, line or region information. You need add many other modules and tune them to get the best results.

First, image preprocessing is necessary for camera OCR application. Background, noise removal, binarization, resize ... should be added to clean image as possible as you can.

Secondly, you need locate the text region. The algorithm not only depends on image features but also on your OCR objective. For example, if you need to OCR plate number, you can use the plate number's length, width or height for more accurate location.

After OCR, you can add some post processing to correct some OCR errors. Common OCR engines such as Abyy, ExperVision, Omnipage, GOCR, Tesseract are all trained according to common documents, magazine or office paper. If your documents are special, you can establish your high-level data extraction or analysis logic over OCR layer.Permalink